# How to change color of one column in R reactable?

Tags: r, reactable

I have created a reactable "MasterIndexTable" where the final column "Rank" in the table is a value 1 through 435. I have defined a color palette so the cell with 1 gets a red color and 435 gets a blue color. However, since the background colors from that palette are dark I want to change the font of those cell values to white.

I'm not sure how to edit an individual column's font color? I'm assuming it happens within the [Rank - colDef] component?

```
RtoDColorPalette <- function(x) rgb(colorRamp(c("red","blue"))(x),maxColorValue = 255)

MasterIndexTable <- reactable(
  HousePVI,
  columns = list(
    ID_No = colDef(show = FALSE),
    State = colDef(defaultSortOrder = "asc", width = 60),
    District_Number = colDef(name = "District", defaultSortOrder = "asc", width = 70),
    First_Name = colDef(name = "First Name"),
    Last_Name = colDef(name = "Last Name"),
    Member_Party = colDef(name = "Party", width = 60),
    PVI_Lean = colDef(name = "PVI Lean", width = 60),
    PVI_Value = colDef(name = "PVI Value", width = 60),
    Rank = colDef(name = "Rank (Most Republican (1) to Most Democratic (435)", width = 230,  
              style = function(value) {
                normalized <- (value - min(HousePVI$Rank))/(max(HousePVI$Rank) min(HousePVI$Rank))
                color <- RtoDColorPalette(normalized)
                list(background = color)
                }
              )
    ),
  theme = reactableTheme(
    color = 'black',
    backgroundColor = 'white',
    borderColor = 'black',
    stripedColor = 'aliceblue' )
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your style function add `color="white"` to the returned `list`.

Using some fake data:

```
library(reactable)

set.seed(123)

RtoDColorPalette <- function(x) rgb(colorRamp(c("red", "blue"))(x), maxColorValue = 255)

HousePVI <- data.frame(
  ID_No = 1:10,
  State = LETTERS[1:10],
  Rank = sample(1:10)
)

reactable(
  HousePVI,
  columns = list(
    ID_No = colDef(show = FALSE),
    Rank = colDef(
      name = "Rank (Most Republican (1) to Most Democratic (435)", width = 230,
      style = function(value) {
        normalized <- (value - min(HousePVI$Rank)) / (max(HousePVI$Rank) - min(HousePVI$Rank))
        color <- RtoDColorPalette(normalized)
        list(background = color, color = "white")
      }
    )
  ),
  theme = reactableTheme(
    color = "black",
    backgroundColor = "white",
    borderColor = "black",
    stripedColor = "aliceblue"
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: I figured it was a quick fix. So this specification will override any "theme" color later defined?

Comment: Yup. Every style you set inside `colDef` will override or has a higher priority as the style set via the theme.